# How to update the date to the previous month, but keep the day static at the first of the month? The import doesn't populate the date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

We have an excel import, but it doesn't have the date. I wanna populate the date in access, so is there a way I could do that on the table or could I create an after update macro to populate the date after import automatically? I was able to get the formula "? Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date()), "mmyy")" to get the previous month, but I've been struggling to make the day part of the date static

Comment: Or `Format(DateAdd("m",-1,Date()), "mm/1/yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateSerial` to obtain the first day of the previous month:

```
DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1)
```